# How to return back the function call and its parameters within the same function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

Without using anything that has been deprecated and **without passing as a parameter** to the function call, can we return the entire function call with the exact parameters?

For example, we have:

```
function MyFunction(param1, param2, param3) {
    var f = function() {
        MyFunction(param1, param2, param3); // Made an edit here.  This would make more sense.
    }

    return(f); // I really don't want to define f.
}

var capture = MyFunction(1, 2, 3);

capture();
```

Instead of hard coding the function call to the f variable, can we use some keyword or JavaScript function instead and thus require no maintenance?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what exactly you are trying to achieve? The function itself of course knows which arguments have been passed to it, but I'm not quite sure what your end goal is.

Comment: The entire function call will be saved, but only after the function was executed.  The saved function will be re-called at a later time.

Comment: I should say there are nice promises involved in the function, so we can't just save it right after the function call.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to call the same function multiple times maybe have a look at [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)

Comment: Again, there are promises involved and therefore the entire function call must be returned using a callback or promise-resolve).  The callback is where the entire function call will be re-initiated.

Comment: Why does the function have to do that? Why can't the caller make the necessary arrangements? It's the caller who calls the function after all.

Answer (score 0):

Why not return another function inside function?

```
function MyFunction(param1, param2, param3) {
    return function() {
        return param1+param2+param3;
    }
}

var capture = MyFunction(1, 2, 3);

capture();
```

Comment: hmmm..I  tested that by putting an alert in the function and it only alerted 1 time.  I expected 2 alerts.

Comment: Then give some implementation inside `MyFunction`that will execute and when return again that will execute ?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be fully generalized, a function can refer (only named functions) itself with its name, there's no common reference to the currently executed function. The snippet below does what you need, when you're having a named function, which is not a method of an object.

```js
function captureFn(fn, args) {
  return function() {
    fn.call(null, ...args);
  };
}

function MyFunction(param1, param2, param3) {
  console.log(param1, param2, param3);
  return captureFn(MyFunction, arguments);
}

var capture = MyFunction(1, 2, 3);

capture();
```

In the return statement of `MyFunction` you've to change the first argument to the name of the function on every function this return value is used.

This is easy to expand to cover object methods too. Just pass `this` as an argument to `captureFn`, and pass the passed `this` instead of `null` in `fn.call`. When calling from an object method, the function can be also anonymous, the function name can be replaced with a reference to the method (`this.methodName`). See this variation [working at jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wts9juo1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) to call the function multiple times.

Using `Promise.then`

```js
async function* func(...props) {
  for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    const result = await new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve(props[i]), 1000)
    );

    yield result;
  }
}

let generator = func(1, 2, 3);

generator.next().then((val) => {
  console.log(val);
});

generator.next().then((val) => {
  console.log(val);
});

generator.next().then((val) => {
  console.log(val);
});
```

Using `Async/Await`

```js
async function* func(...props) {
  for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    const result = await new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve(props[i]), 1000)
    );

    yield result;
  }
}

(async () => {
  let generator = func(1, 2, 3);

  console.log(await generator.next());
  console.log(await generator.next());
  console.log(await generator.next());
})();
```